# Is there a way to disable browser cache for a single page?

Tags: php, apache, caching, xampp

For a small intranet site, I have a dynamic (includes AJAX) page that is being cached incorrectly by Firefox. Is there a way to disable browser caching for a single page?

Here's the setup I'm using:

- Apache under XAMPP, running on a Windows server
- PHP

### Clarification

The content that I'm primarily concerned about is page text and the default options in some `<select>`s. So I can't just add random numbers to the end of some image URLs, for example.

### Update:

I followed the suggestions I've gotten so far:

- I'm sending nocache headers (see below)
- I'm including a timestamp URL parameter and redirecting to a new one if the page is reloaded after 2 seconds, like this:

  ```
  $timestamp = $_GET['timestamp'];
  if ((time()-$timestamp) > 2) {
      header('Location:/intranet/admin/manage_skus.php?timestamp='.time());
  }
  ```

Now Firebug shows that the headers specify no cache, but the problem persists. Here are the response headers for the page:

```
Date    Fri, 25 Sep 2009 20:41:43 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.8
Expires Mon, 20 Dec 1998 01:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Fri, 25 Sep 2009 20:41:43 GMT
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma  no-cache
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html
```

Comment: How do you know it's incorrectly cached?

Comment: @Martin - I'm not 100% sure, but reloading makes it display wrong, while Ctr+F5 reloading (which clears cache) fixes it. Before the reload, I'm using Ajax to add rows to a table (and to the database) based on user input. I put them on top and use a highlight effect to make it clear what's happening. After the reload, those same rows should be in the table but ordered based on the MySQL query. At that point, Firefox doesn't associate the correct data with the correct row, as though it's using some information from the previous row order.

Comment: OK - further clarification: all that's being displayed incorrectly is the default option in a <select> on each row. The correct option has `selected="selected"` in it (according to Firebug), but the actual dropdown shows something else until Ctrl+F5 is pressed.

Answer (score 9):

Add current timestamp as parameter of url, e.g.

```
http://server.com/index.php?timestamp=125656789
```

Comment: This is the best answer since older browsers (i am looking at you IE) don't follow the no-cache header in some situations.

Comment: Do this on the link? What about regular page refreshes?

Comment: Redirect browser to new timestamp, if timestamp passed by param is too old.

Answer (score 4):

I think this tells you what you want:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/phptutorial2.shtml

Look for "Preventing the Browser From Caching"

```
header( "Expires: Mon, 20 Dec 1998 01:00:00 GMT" );
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT" );
header( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header( "Pragma: no-cache" );
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So far no change, though. I edited my question to show the response headers I'm getting.

Answer (score 3):

You should send the following header:

```
Cache-control: no-cache
```

in the HTTP response.

Comment: I did this, using Craig Treptow's code suggestion, but no dice. I edited the question to show the headers.

Answer (score 1):

You could add these headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And (for backward compatibility with HTTP/1.0 clients)

```
Pragma: no-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take that isn't PHP specific.

Try this in your `<head> </head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no store"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" Content="Mon, 25 May 2009 19:07:03 GMT">
```

Found that at the end of a long thread here:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=673135&start=75

Answer (score 0):

Use the header() function. You have to set a few to cover all browsers; see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#75507